# View several lines from a file in a tar.gz file

Tags: bash, view, command-line, gzip, tar

I have a very large .tar file that contains several .gz files. I would like to view a few lines in any of the individual files without untarring. I can view the files using:

```
tar -tzf TarFile # doesn't actually end in .tar
```

I get:

```
TarFile/
FileA.gz
FileB.gz
FileC.gz
FileD.gz
```

I would like to view just a few lines from any of the individual files. Normally I would use:

```
zless MyFile
```

Is there a way to combine the two commands so I can view a few lines from any of the individual files?

Answer (score 1):

```
tar -xOf TarFile FileB.gz | zless
```

Explanation:

`tar`

`-x`

`-O` extract to standard output

`-f Tarfile`

`FileB.gz` the file in the tar archive to extract

`| zless` pipe the extracted file data to zless

This will be expensive to do more than once as it requires tar to scan the archive each time you run the command. If the tar archive is large (and the file you want is early in the tarball) you might also benefit from using `--occurrence=1` on that command line to get tar to stop processing the tar file immediately when it finds a file that matches the file you told it to extract.

Comment: Seems like it should work. However instead of seeing normal text I'm seeing a lot of "^_<88>^H^@^@^@^@^D<FF><AC><BD><D9>r<E3>"... My files are in fastq format but should be readable like a regular text file. If I try to view another fastq.gz file that isn't in a tar file I can view using zless just fine.

Comment: If you extract the file with `tar -xf TarFile FileB.gz` and then run `zless FileB.gz` does it work? What does `file FileB.gz` say? What does `file` say if you run `gunzip FileB.gz; file FileB`?

Comment: that works. Unfortunately I seem to have now written over the original tar file with a folder containing the one .gz file. Any quick way to revert?

Comment: You've removed the tarball `TarFile` and now have a `TarFile` directory containing `FileB.gz`? No. You can't "revert" filesystem changes like that on most filesystems.